# How to sort by a number field?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7

When using the new Search API `(ContentSearchManager.GetIndex...)`, how can we sort the result by a numeric field. When using default `.OrderBy()`, then the field is sorted by the string representation of these numbers.

This means that the order is like:

```
1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5...
```

How can we instruct SiteCore to sort this field as a number?

I have found [a answer on how to do this in 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685490/lucene-net-sorting-by-int), but we are using 7.

Comment: Also interested in the answer. There has to be a way since they need to do this in the content editor with the sort order field.

Comment: @ddysart: you can do this the way sitecore climber describes, but then using [IndexField("__sortorder")]. Not fully sure of the syntax here, I would have to check, but you get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have mappingItem to be something like  :

```
public class MappingItem 
{ 
 [IndexField("orderingnumberIndex")] 
 int OrderingNumber {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: You can use a tool like Luke to check what's in your index, and how it's stored.